# Excel pivot data / tilt columns

Tags: excel

I need help with Excel (using 2016) to get data in a specific format. Currently I have the data like this:

```
Date        MTA  Amt
01.02.16    WU   2 
01.02.16    WU   2
01.02.16    WU   1
01.02.16    MG   8 
02.02.16    MG   4 
02.02.16    MG   1
02.02.16    CC   6.2
```

I want to get this format:

```
Date      HP  CC   MG    WU
1/2/2016           8     5  
2/2/2016      6.2  5
```

Comment: and a pivot table is not working for you?

Comment: @ScottCraner No, I have thousands of rows. need an automated way in excel

Comment: Then to get from what you have automatically you will want vba.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to fill your second table using this formula:

```
=if(sumifs(S1!C:C,S1!A:A,$A2,S1!B:B,B$1)>0,sumifs(S1!C:C,S1!A:A,$A2,S1!B:B,B$1),"")
```

assuming your source data is in sheet "S1". [reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: Yes it is in S1 but not getting any output from the above formula when i paste it in cell D2? Do I need to do something special with formula above?